# Kafka csv processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question about processing of files and putting them in Kafka topics. For now we're processing files via csv library, making some calculation in java and putting the result in kafka topics. It's batch operation. Files are processed every several hours. Then this data is spreading to microservices that need this data. I know that Kafka has stream api, and I can do the same calculation in real-time. My question is whether I have to pay attention to kafka streams. Because data is processed only every couple hours and time of processing is absolutely suit for current requirements. I'd like to hear an advice from you. Thank you in advance

Comment: Keep it simple. If it works, what would you expect to gain if you change it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a Kafka producer. Running in batch is your only option for sending that data because your input source is still batch.

Kafka isn't meant for *file-processing*, though. The max message size is 1MB by default. You can put CSV *lines* in a topic, but then you might lose ordering guarantees (if you care).
Plus, CSV is often frowned upon in Kafka topics because you lose context of any column meaning.

It's not clear how you consume the results from Kafka, but Streams can help you read the sent results and forward them to a new topic or be embedded into your microservices as a KTable.